# Why do miners seem to be using consecutive letters for the Coinbase transaction text?

Tags: coinbase-transaction, bip-34

If you look at coin.dance, it looks like the coinbase transactions text start with consecutive letters. For example, [block 478529 starts with "AM"](https://blockchain.info/tx/aa51c1618e787679af008f0901830b9ab87eba51df81d17919dae9b511878611) and [478530 starts with "BM"](https://blockchain.info/tx/a612d4aa7f440b354f0494c7e144a110772c46303e5522bd9a369f11240b365f) and [478531 starts with "CM"](https://blockchain.info/tx/3a84d59eed9d92f6d9410b8edc0e947b2a2b46dd5652dee0031dc9250afc1e9b) and so on. This continues with DM, EM, ... all the way to [ZM](https://blockchain.info/tx/05527b538c76d81b3003e7f9d8852a8fad338ee348ef3111ec084775d68da79f) despite being mined by lots of different miners.

This looks coordinated in some way. Why is this? Can't the coinbase text be whatever the miner wants?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [BIP 34](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0034.mediawiki) the coinbase transaction is required to start with the block height.  The format is a single byte giving the count of bytes to follow (currently 3) and then the block height in little-endian. See [Why block height is required in coinbase?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/30764/why-block-height-is-required-in-coinbase) for more on the rationale.

478529 decimal is 0x074d41 in hex, so this block's coinbase must begin with the bytes `0x03 0x41 0x4d 0x07`.  `0x41 0x4d` happen to be the ASCII codes for the letters `A M`.

Likewise, 478530 decimal is 0x074d42, so we start with `0x03 0x42 0x4d 0x07`, and `0x42 0x4d` is `B M`.