# Why does transaction d5d27987d2a3dfc724e359870c6644b40e497bdc0589a033220fe15429d88599 included in two different blocks?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I'm not sure i get it right and i thoughts, in theory, it's not possible.
But i stumbled with that transaction d5d27987d2a3dfc724e359870c6644b40e497bdc0589a033220fe15429d88599 and indeed, https://blockchain.info/tx/d5d27987d2a3dfc724e359870c6644b40e497bdc0589a033220fe15429d88599 two different blocks include that transaction.

Can someone explain me why and how does it happen?

Thank you

Comment: Also related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/30764/why-block-height-is-required-in-coinbase/30780#30780, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5903/where-can-i-learn-more-about-bip30-namely-the-exploit-and-the-background-discus/5905#5905